# Hazelcast client config fails if one of many servers down

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have this code where
hazelcastAddr is an array of URL strings.

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    config.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", LOGGING_TYPE);
    for (String hazelcastAddr : hazelcastAddrArray) {
        LOG.trace("Hazelcast attempting to add network config for ip address <<{}>>.", hazelcastAddr);

        config.getNetworkConfig().addAddress(hazelcastAddr);
    }

    return config;

hazelcastInstance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
```

If hazelcastAddr gives four different URL Strings (for four different instances) and they are all currently up and running then things go as expected. However, if one (or two or three) are down then it throws an exception and fails to return an instance of the HazelcastClient. However, since it is able to connect to at least one it seems to me that it should still connect and the running instance(s) should be able to give it the current state of the system for it to work correctly.

Please update me on how to get this behaviour or if I am missing something and this should be the correct behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DavidR, client connects always 1 of the address. And this connection is not made while creating,setting config object. `hazelcastInstance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);`  this code starts a client and tries to connect given address respectively.  or I don't understand your problem well.

Comment: The last line of that code is going to throw the exception. It will do so because we called config.getNetworkConfig().addAddress(hazelcastAddr) three times and one of those three instances of Hazelcast are currently down.

Comment: @BilalYasar - I see how the LOG statements in my code confused things. I was wrong about where I thought the original exception was being thrown.  I have cleaned up the example.

Comment: i will try to reproduce your case today and try to write an unit test. Lets see results.